# Which command to use to restart postgresql 12 service

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-12

I am about to restart postgresql 12 service running on Ubuntu 18.
First, I check it's status : `sudo service postgresql status`. Its says :

```
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor pres
   Active: inactive (dead)
lines 1-3/3 (END)...skipping...
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Although it appears to be inactive, but I still can connect.

Then I run another checking : `systemctl status postgresql@12-main`. it says :

```
root@db-services:/# systemctl status postgresql@12-main
● postgresql@12-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 12-main
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/postgresql@12-main.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/postgresql@12-main.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-06-13 09:02:25 WIB; 5 months 27 days ago
 Main PID: 5807 (postgres)
    Tasks: 86 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-postgresql.slice/postgresql@12-main.service
           ├─ 1586 postgres: 12/main: postgres db_sync 10.100.3.248(61414) idle
           ├─ 1588 postgres: 12/main: postgres db_sync 10.100.3.248(61415) idle
           ├─ 1606 postgres: 12/main: docreg db_docreg 10.100.8.150(18385) idle
           ├─ 1607 postgres: 12/main: docreg db_docreg 10.100.8.150(18399) idle
           ├─ 1608 postgres: 12/main: docreg db_docreg 10.100.8.150(18401) idle
           ├─ 1609 postgres: 12/main: docreg db_docreg 10.100.8.150(18421) idle
           ├─ 2592 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.8.112(34956) idle
           ├─ 3518 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(48290) idle
           ├─ 5150 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.7.114(61504) idle
           ├─ 5807 /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres -D /data/postgresql/12/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.co
           ├─ 5883 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(48626) idle
           ├─ 6316 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(48704) idle
           ├─ 7049 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(48870) idle
           ├─ 7986 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.7.114(56240) idle
           ├─ 8146 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.8.114(47432) idle
           ├─ 8183 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(49022) idle
           ├─ 8360 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(49036) idle
           ├─ 8445 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.8.114(47478) idle
           ├─ 9590 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.8.106(56094) idle
           ├─ 9687 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.8.112(50980) idle
           ├─10148 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(40646) idle
           ├─10324 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(40680) idle
           ├─11079 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(49496) idle
           ├─11602 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(58152) idle
           ├─11886 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(44674) idle
           ├─12106 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(49618) idle
           ├─13112 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.6.145(55014) idle
           ├─13122 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.6.145(55015) idle
           ├─13145 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_mysapk 10.100.6.145(55016) idle
           ├─13202 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.7.114(62073) idle
           ├─13945 postgres: 12/main: checkpointer
           ├─13946 postgres: 12/main: background writer
           ├─13947 postgres: 12/main: walwriter
           ├─13948 postgres: 12/main: autovacuum launcher
           ├─13949 postgres: 12/main: stats collector
           ├─13950 postgres: 12/main: logical replication launcher
```

So it is actually active !

Then I do `sudo service --status-all | grep postgresql`. It says :

```
[ - ]  postgresql
```

1. Whats the difference between `systemctl restart postgresql@12-main` **VS** `sudo service postgresql restart`?
2. Which one should I use for restart : `systemctl restart postgresql@12-main` **OR** `sudo service postgresql restart` ?

For comparison, on another server, if I do `sudo service postgresql status`. It says :

```
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2022-12-05 18:37:03 WIT; 4 days ago
  Process: 22666 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 22666 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 05 18:37:03 db-profile-mtr systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Dec 05 18:37:03 db-profile-mtr systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

And when I do `systemctl status postgresql@12-main`, it says :

```
postgresql@12-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 12-main
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/postgresql@12-main.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-12-05 18:37:03 WIT; 4 days ago
  Process: 22609 ExecStop=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect -m fast 12-main stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 22631 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 12-main start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 22637 (postgres)
    Tasks: 119 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-postgresql.slice/postgresql@12-main.service
           ├─  417 postgres: 12/main: refer db_ref 10.100.9.50(53216) idle
           ├─  965 postgres: 12/main: refer db_ref 10.100.9.50(53514) idle
           ├─ 1709 postgres: 12/main: profiling db_profile 127.0.0.1(34158) idle
     ...many proceses all the way down
```

Then I do `sudo service --status-all | grep postgresql`. And it says :

```
 [ + ]  postgresql
```

Need advice / help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably neither, as there are actually two variables:

1. Command.

   - The `service` command is *legacy* from SysVInit.
   - The `systemctl` comes with SystemD and replaces SysVInit; use it.
2. Postgresql services on Ubuntu.

   - `postgresql.service` controls all Postgresql instances.
   - `postgresql@12-main.service` is a single instance; there could be multiple.

To restart all instances: `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`.

There's a [longer explanation on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/884057).

Comment: Finally I did it using `sudo service postgresql restart`. Now when I do `sudo service postgresql status` it shows : 
`postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2022-12-11 00:38:06 WIB; 11s ago
  Process: 3095 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3095 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)` . All is well.  Thanks @EsaJokinen.